# Why is my registration form not updating on submit

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm making a registration form using Flask-wtforms and sqlite as my database but when I try to submit it does not push to the database.

I have checked whether i had not put a method of 'post'in my registration form and also whether my db had been created when i configured it.

## This my forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileAllowed
from flask_login import current_user
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo, ValidationError
from app.models import User
from app import db


class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username',
                           validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    picture=FileField('Profile picture',validators=[DataRequired(),FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'])])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password',
                                     validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')
    def validate_username(self, username):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError('That username is taken. Please choose a different one.')

    def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError('That email is taken. Please choose a different one.')
```

## Register.html

```
<form action="" method="POST" class='register-form'>
                      {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                      <div class=''>
                    {{form.picture.label}}
                    {{form.picture}}
                    {%if error in form.picture.errors%}
                    <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                    {% endif %}
                  </div>
                      <p >
                          {{ form.username.label }}<br>
                          {{ form.username(size=32) }}<br>
                          {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                          <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                          {% endfor %}
                      </p>
                      <p>
                          {{ form.email.label }}<br>
                          {{ form.email(size=32) }}<br>
                          {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                          <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                          {% endfor %}
                      </p>
                      <p>
                          {{ form.password.label }}<br>
                          {{ form.password(size=32) }}<br>
                          {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                          <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                          {% endfor %}
                      </p>
                      <p>
                          {{ form.confirm_password.label }}<br>
                          {{ form.confirm_password(size=32) }}<br>
                          {% for error in form.confirm_password.errors %}
                          <span style="color: red;">  [{{"Typo! Passwords didn't match"}}]</span>
                          {% endfor %}
                      </p>
                      <p>{{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary")   }}</p>
                    
                  </form>
```

## Where i have configured my sqlite db

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'hidden secret key8e9808798709809'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///users.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
manager = Manager(app)
```

No error message i just know that it is not pushing new users to the db.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Hope this helps someone out there ..lol...

## adding to the register.html

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This way the request.files won't be empty